# AJAX data passed to PHP file gives 'Undefined Index" error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have this `ajax` snippet to pass the data to the particular `php` file. The passing data is the name of a `html element`

**Here's my `ajax` code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(imgno);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/upload-ad-image-inc.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "html",
             data: {
            imgno: imgno
        }
    });
});
```

values for `imgno` will be : **1,2,3,4,.....**

and this is my **upload-ad-image-inc.php**

```
$imageNO = $_POST['imgno'];

$sql = "UPDATE user SET userFName='$imageNO' WHERE  userid=1;";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

But I get this error saying **undefined index: imgno**

**but what is confusing is, when i change the php file to another php, i works**

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What does *"when I change to another php"* mean?

Comment: @charlietfl when I create a new php file and change the `url` to it

Comment: Clearly something different between the two that we can't see then

Comment: Maybe caching? Try `Ctrl` + `F5`.

Comment: @charlietfl no, just found the problem and is i'm accessing the same PHP file with 2 ajax functions. Can you tell me a solution for that?

Comment: @Xufox no, just found the problem and is i'm accessing the same PHP file with 2 ajax functions. Can you tell me a solution for that?

Comment: add inverted quo-ma "imgno" :imgno try this

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem and a solution:

It throws `undefined index` error when you have **multiple ajax functions calling the same PHP file**

To overcome this problem, check the passing data using `isset()` in PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['imgno'])) { 
    $imageNO = $_POST['imgno'];

    $sql = "UPDATE user SET userFName='$imageNO' WHERE  userid=1;";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Also, in order to avoid SQL injection attack, try to make use of "prepared mysql queries."